# Is there a way to connect a field Boolean output to a geometry switch node?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

As you can see I am trying to connect the output of a Boolean Math node to the input of a Switch node set to Geometry. The problem is that it not possible because part of the Boolean node comes from a field. You can not connect this to a Switch node set to Geometry. I am not at all an expert when it comes blender geometry nodes. Is there a work around to this or is there a node for this? Any help is much appreciated!!!

[image: text]

Comment: Could you, at some point, mark elements of the geometry with the boolean, and use _Delete Geometry_  or _Separate Geometry_ instead? Hard to say, without more context.

Comment: What is shown is the end a loop step that is locating vertices that are coincident to an edge but not connected. If it finds one for a vertex it modifies the geometry so the vertex is welded to the edge. What I am trying to accomplish is stopping the search for that index after it fins one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert multiple values to **a single value**, either:

- use *Attribute Statistic* node in order to evaluate **a single value** based on all/selected values:

[image]

- use *Sample Index* node to pick **a single value** out of multiple values:

[image]

If this doesn't help you, it's likely an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and you need to rephrase your question to show what's the real (Y) problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMLpN.png]

It seems I had not looked at the *Sample By Index* node close enough. I was not aware it was both a field and value node. So if I understand it correctly the image above should do the trick. I have emphasized the nodes that input to the Boolean node in question just for clarification.