# Get information about spline cyclicity

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, splines

1. How can I get the information whether the spline is cyclic or not?

[image]

The example shown above does not work.
What is wrong with my approach?

2. With this method (Capture attribute), I manage to get information, for example, about normals, but not about the cyclicity of the spline. If possible, I would like to know why the blender works so selectively?

[image](Blender 3.6.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem seems to be an issue with Blender. It's not a bug in the sense that the node tree works like it's supposed to, however the pink Switch socket of the *Switch* node probably should have a circular shape. This is because the output is circular (evaluated once per frame per geonodes modifier), so all inputs should be circular as well. And then, if you connected a field to a circular socket, the link would become red, reporting an error, which you can fix by [converting multiple values to a single value](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296337/60486). In your case, there could possibly be more than one spline, so tell Blender you mean the first spline (index 0):

[image]

The text still says *No*, because at the sampled point, the spline wasn't cyclic. Perhaps you want to sample later in the evaluation:

[image]

But it still says *No*, because the *Cyclic* attribute change doesn't propagate to all attributes affected by it - this is precisely the reason why you would capture an attribute, to be able to keep its original value as a copy. So what you want to do is just read the actual *Cyclic* field from the *Is Spline Cyclic* node:

[image]

And as I just showed, you don't need the *Capture Attribute* node in this case.

Comment: Thank you. As I understood, it is the "Sample index" that is responsible for reading the actual information about object.

Comment: @arachnoden it evaluates the **Value** field as type **Boolean** on the first (**Index** 0) **Spline** in the connected **Geometry**.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer from @MarkusvonBroady should be sufficient for your needs. Here is just an additional / alternative version: in Blender, a curve object consisting of several splines can have different *Cyclic* settings under *Active Spline* in the *Curve Properties* for each spline. Of course you can set them individually in *Geometry Nodes* as well, but it seems not many people know that even without GN, a curve does not necessarily have all cyclic or non-cyclic splines.

So, if you get rid of the *Set Spline Cyclic* node (or mute it), the splines will use the individual settings given in the *Curve Properties*. In the follwoing example I simply duplicated the spline a few times in *Edit Mode* and set some of them to *Cyclic* and some not:

[image: multiple splines]

Now you could use a *Sample Curve* node set to *Boolean* instead of *Sample Index*, because this way you can not only get the *Cyclic* information of the spline determined by the *Curve Index*, but also the position of the respective spline (in this case it is the location of the first control point).

[image: sample curve]

This can be used e.g. to switch through the individual splines and show there *Cyclic* status and even place the text next to the spline in question. As I said, this might not be needed, it is just an additional way of retrieving information.

[image: switching between splines]